# Content Security Policy: Should a CSP contain hashes for external scripts?

Tags: javascript, xss, content-security-policy

### What I am unsure about

I am wondering if the `Content-Security-Policy` header should/can contain hashes for [external JavaScript files](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) (aka, tags with a `src` attribute `<script src="foo.js"></script>`).

### What I have tried

In Chromium based browsers and Mozilla Firefox, my external scripts are blocked, even when including all of those scripts' hashes in the `Content-Security-Policy` header:

```
script-src 'sha256-Dxn+cR58x5haydQ1S/lvgMBLRahDCNxsakeubYGDJD0=' 'sha256-WiXxwK6878G5m29xzbpoI/6mHv7Otw1epCuigPupglA=' 'sha256-B5Xt87JgO41oTYQ2MabCc4UUuiVbcT/ingSs4HJHt1U=';
```

I have also tried

```
script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'sha256-Dxn+cR58x5haydQ1S/lvgMBLRahDCNxsakeubYGDJD0=' 'sha256-WiXxwK6878G5m29xzbpoI/6mHv7Otw1epCuigPupglA=' 'sha256-B5Xt87JgO41oTYQ2MabCc4UUuiVbcT/ingSs4HJHt1U=';
```

My HTML containing the external scripts:

```
...

        <!-- These are Webpack generated scripts built with the Angular CLI -->
        <script src="runtime.78e54b12002286474edb.js"></script>
        <script src="polyfills.73e66b75888e8a86f685.js"></script>
        <script src="main.4deb3029247017da53f3.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### What I expect to happen

I am expecting the browser to hash the contents of external JavaScript files, and compare those hashes with those found in the `Content-Security-Policy` header's `script-src` attribute (thus verifying the integrity of any delivered JavaScript files against what my server has whitelisted in the CSP header).

### CSP Spec on hashing external JS

Mozilla states in their `script-src` documentation. **Notice the last sentence**

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src

#### '<hash-algorithm>-<base64-value>'

A sha256, sha384 or sha512 hash of scripts or styles. The use of this source consists of two portions separated by a dash: the encryption algorithm used to create the hash and the base64-encoded hash of the script or style. When generating the hash, don't include the  or  tags and note that capitalization and whitespace matter, including leading or trailing whitespace. See unsafe inline script for an example. In CSP 2.0, this is applied only to inline scripts. **CSP 3.0 allows it in the case of script-src for external scripts.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDN documentation you referred is just popular information therefore it does not contain details.

According to [CSP3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#external-hash), `<script>` elements would be allowed to execute only if they contain **integrity metadata** that matches the hashes in the policy.

Add an *integrity=* attribute into script tags like that:

```
<!-- These are Webpack generated scripts built with the Angular CLI -->
<script src="runtime.78e54b12002286474edb.js" integrity="sha256-...."></script>
<script src="polyfills.73e66b75888e8a86f685.js" integrity="sha256-...."></script>
<script src="main.4deb3029247017da53f3.js" integrity="sha256-...."></script>
```

and `'hash-value'` will begin to work. But, unfortunately, in [Chrome only](https://csplite.com/csp/test161/#conclusions). Safari and Firefox did not implement this yet.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm experiencing with Firefox, and it's limiting my ability to add integrity checks to my static application. I'd read the W3C's spec as well, but was still unclear on the use of the integrity attribute with CSP. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an order in which hashes in the policy are evaluated against hashes in integrity attributes?